# how to dismiss popup dialog by moving it to up or to down or to right or to left

Tags: android, dialog, ontouchlistener

I I have a popup dialog , i want to dismiss it like facebook comments dialog or dialog for images , like this pics

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am facing same problem did you find any solution.

Comment: no i can't find any solution :(